# Can i use gnomonic projection in OpenLayers?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I am a novice at OpenLayers, I used it and GeoServer to build a gis web page.

Does OpenLayers support gnomonic projection? Or can I implement it in a custom way like "ol/proj/Projection"?

I set up geoServer to publish the map as a WMTS service, and now I can display the map and add features through OpenLayers.

If I want to use gnomonic projection, do I need to provide new data and publish new layers in GeoServer?

**2020/10/9**

Thanks for Mike, I tried to use pro4js and got a different map.

I still use my previous data source. For now, there is no problem with the zoom and drag functions of the map. The current page looks like this:
[image: now page]

The current code is like this:

```js
import "ol/ol.css";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import proj4 from "proj4";
import {
    get as getProjection
} from "ol/proj";
import {
    register
} from "ol/proj/proj4";

import {
    getWidth,
    getTopLeft
} from 'ol/extent'
import WMTS from 'ol/source/WMTS'
import WMTSTileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/WMTS'


proj4.defs(
    "GNOM",
    "+proj=gnom +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=EPSG:3857 +datum=EPSG:3857 +units=m +no_defs"
)
register(proj4)

var gnom = getProjection("GNOM")
var merc = getProjection('EPSG:900913')
gnom.setExtent(merc.getExtent())
var projectionExtent = merc.getExtent()
var size = getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256
var resolutions = new Array(9)
var matrixIds = new Array(9)
for (var z = 0; z < 9; ++z) {
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z)
    matrixIds[z] = "EPSG:900913:" + z
}

let wmtsTileGrid = new WMTSTileGrid({
    origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
    resolutions: resolutions,
    matrixIds: matrixIds
})

let map_source = new WMTS({
    url: 'http://10.1.1.4:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
    layer: "world_weitu:world_l8",
    matrixSet: 'EPSG:900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    projection: gnom,
    tileGrid: wmtsTileGrid,
    wrapX: true
})

var map = new Map({
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: map_source
        })
    ],
    target: "map",
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5
    })
});
```

Now i can drag and zoom the map, but the center of the view is always at [0, 0], is there any way to make the center of the view always at the center of the screen(Respond to drag operations)?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use any projection supported by proj4js https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-tdd-sy489?file=/main.js